# Reverse port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port, forwarding

I'm on a windows machine with the ip, x.y.z.1 say. I'm running apache on port 80. i need to be able to access this service from a remote linux box IP a.b.c.2 say... I have ssh access from my local windows machine to the linux box but should I ssh into the box I cannot ping my windows machine from the box. I thought that reverse port forwarding might do the trick for me? I tried

```
ssh -vvv -R 80:localhost:8053 root@a.b.c.2
```

as I understood it that would forward all connections to the address a.b.c.2:8053 to my local windows machine on port 80? But when I attempt to wget on the remote server with the line

```
wget localhost:8053
```

I get connection refused.

Am I misunderstanding the rules behind port forwarding?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a super expert in SSH Forwarding but I think you need to use a local port rather than a remote, so your command line should look like

```
ssh -L 8053:localhost:80 <host>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-R 80:localhost:8053
```

You have the port numbers backwards. The first number is the port number to *listen to* on the *remote* host. The second number, along with the hostname, is the address and port to *connect to* from the *local* host.

Try it this way:

```
ssh -vvv -R 8053:localhost:80 root@a.b.c.2
```